# How do you securely implement a finite field?

Tags: elliptic-curves, implementation, finite-field, side-channel-attack

I'm not sure if this question belongs here or to StackOverflow. Please flag it if not.

I'm trying to implement a standalone library for finite field arithmetic of prime and prime power order as a way to learn to write safe code. Afterwards I plan to implement some elliptic curve groups on top of it and then some elliptic curve algorithms on top of the groups. We will focus on finite fields since for ECC schemes there exist standards but I couldn't find a standard for them.

However, I find it a bit hard to locate online resources like books/papers/standards teaching you common tricks, pitfalls, methodologies, guidelines or even golden/reference implementations with readable code where the community is based to create new libraries.

I also find it troublesome to trust a random Github author to learn from his code and I also find it hard to read a big library's code like OpenSSL's without comments.

My questions are :

What is the community's/professional consensus when it comes to implementing a cryptographic library?

Do you just copy an idea from someone else's implementation? If you do, which implementation you have as a reference?

---

Currently, I'm based on these resources :

https://martin.kleppmann.com/papers/curve25519.pdf

https://www.bearssl.org/bigint.html

Comment: BearSSL is a good starting point, however, keep in mind that, you may find yourself in ASM to get rid of Compillers' unwanted intelligent optimizations. As a side note, watch our [Thomas Pornin T1 language](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IHbtK5Kwt6A)

Comment: I'd guess that you refer with your tag "side-channel-attack" to constant-time only, not differential power analysis or fault attacks. You might get a good impression of the problems you will face by watching the invited talk by Peter Schwabe at [CHES 2023](https://ches.iacr.org/2023/program.php).

Comment: The [Fiat Crypto](https://github.com/mit-plv/fiat-crypto) project generates implementations of finite field arithmetic (I think). Looking at the various publications at the bottom of the readme may help.

Comment: @j.p. I will try to implement such mechanisms afterwards but strangely I have found more resources on how to implement software mitigations for such attacks like PA and FI.